# How to modify files owned by root?

Tags: permissions, root

In trying to resolve another issue...one suggestion was to modify  a file (using gedit) that is owned by Root. It won't let me overwrite the existing file. I am the administrator of this Unity install.

Can someone assist?

Comment: Which file in particular?

Answer (score 2):

First. Be careful editing files owned by root. You could break your system.

In terminal type `gksu gedit /path/to/file`
You will be prompted for your password, enter it.
Gedit will open and you will now be able to edit the file as root.

If gksu isn't installd do so by typing in terminal:
`sudo apt-get install gksu`
After the installation is complete type in terminal:
`gksu-properties`
A window will open. Make sure Autentication mode is set to sudo.

Now you will be able to run graphical applications as root.